# Javascript: How to Upload a large file over HTTP using Transfer encoding header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, rest-client

We have a third party api for uploading a file which requires **Transfer-Encoding** header to be set to **chunked** but this header gets ignored from the header if I set it manually using **xhr.setRequestHeader** . After investigating more on this we found that user agent is responsible for setting this header but seems user agent is only setting Content-Length header. 
Also if we upload a file using following curl command then it works fine.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' -H 'content-type: text/csv' -H 'filename: us-500.csv' -T './Downloads/us-500.csv'  http://serverapi:8090/upload
```

Can someone please help to understand that is there any other way of uploading a large file using Transfer-encoding header.

Answer (score 0):

you're not allowed to set that header as it's controlled by the user agent.

For the full set of headers, see 4.6.2 The setRequestHeader() method from [W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) and note that Transfer-Encoding is one of the headers that are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport.

Accept-Charset
Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Connection
Content-Length
Cookie
Cookie2
Date
DNT
Expect
Host
Keep-Alive
Origin
Referer
TE
Trailer
Transfer-Encoding
Upgrade
User-Agent
Via

There is a similar list in the WhatWG Fetch API Living Standard. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers